# Wordpress: Media Grid loads only the images in the preview and does not show them after saving

Tags: wordpress, grid, media

I use Media Grid for my Wordpress page to display images. Every time I preview the page via preview, the pictures are displayed without any problem, but unfortunately this is not the case anymore after the page has been updated. After saving the page the images are not displayed and the console shows the message "Nothing found".

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"status":"Nothing found"}
    at Function.ea.error (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at ea.tokenize (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at ea.select (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ea (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at n.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at a.fn.init.n.fn.init (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at new a.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at n (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

[image]

I have already searched for this error message in forums and got nowhere. can someone help me fix the problem?
Like this: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/problem-with-wpml-and-visual-composer-grid-builder/

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem with reinstallung the plugin.